# Can I bind an AngularJS model to a hash URL and an HTML input at the same time?

Tags: angularjs

I'm teaching myself Angular and I've looked over a number of examples that show how to bind a model to an HTML input so that they always contain the same text.

I understand that Angular also provides the $location service which works with the URL.

I have an application that I'm thinking of partially rewriting in Angular as a learning example.

In my example, I have an HTML input that I keep synced up with a model using jQuery and also synced up with a hash URL.

Is there a simple way of accomplishing this with AngularJS?

Consider the example application bellow:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script>
        var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

        function FirstController($scope, $location) {
            var data = {
                bar: 'hello world'
            };
            $scope.data = data            
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp">

        <div ng-controller="FirstController">
            <input ng-model="data.bar" />           
            <h2>{{ data.bar }}</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is a simple example showing how the model can be kept synced with a textbox.  I was wondering if it's possible to keep it synced with a hash URL, as well, so that we would have `http://www.example.com#bar=What_The_User_Typed`

Answer (score 0):

What you probably need is the $routeProvider

https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07

Comment: It appears the documentation has changed. This may now be the correct address... https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09

Comment: If you are having a single page app why would you create routes? Just update $location hash right?